# Number of vistors for each flash instance

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, multiple-instances, visitors

I have a question regarding a video chat solution that I am working on. I have a single swf file (viewer.swf), which is used in multiple places on the website (for each performer), and I would like to know the number of visitors for each of those places.

I currently have the number of visitors from the swf file written to a txt file, but I need this information for each performer.

I am using ModenaChat.

How do I go about doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Your SWF file Monitoring implements a little difficult. maybe, you must have a Server and Database. and more needs complex Server-side Communication.

so i recommend this site: https://www.mochibot.com/index.html

mochibot is awesome SWF Monitoring Platform..

Comment: Thank you, but I would need to put this in a database. I am at a complete loss.

Comment: Google Analytics can track flash too, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/flashTrackingIntro

Comment: Well, I have a variable inside the swf which tells me how many users are connected. This variable is written in a text file. Now, this gives me only one number. However, the flash is used in multiple places at the same time. I would need the individual number of users wherever that flash is being used.